# What is the Haskell equivalence of PHP's associative array

Tags: haskell, associative-array

In PHP I can do this:

```
$array = [
    'A' => [1,2,3],
    'B' => [4,5,6],
    'C' => [7,8,9],
]
```

What is the Haskell equivalence of PHP's associative array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My impression is that you are looking for a key to value map data structure. In that case Haskell has [`Data.Map`](https://haskell-containers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/map.html) provided by the [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package. There are a few variations to it including  [Data.Map.Strict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html), [Data.Map.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html), and [Data.IntMap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-IntMap.html).

Haskell's default map implementations are ordered and based on a balanced tree which makes operations of *logarithmic* time complexity. But there is also a hashing implementation in the [`unordered-containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) package which provides for *constant* operation times but you don't get the default ordering of keys of course.

A short example following the PHP associative array example that you provided:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map


myMap = Map.fromList  [ ('A',[1,2,3])
                      , ('B',[4,5,6])
                      , ('C',[7,8,9])
                      ]

-- Looking up an existing key
Map.lookup 'B' myMap
> Just [4,5,6]

-- Looking up a non-existing key
Map.lookup 'Z' myMap
> Nothing
```

Some more context on how to use a `Map` in Haskell taken from the documentation of `Data.Map`:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

nums = Map.fromList [(1,"one"), (2,"two"), (3,"three")]

-- Get the English word for the number 3 and 4.
Map.lookup 3 nums
> Just "three"

Map.lookup 4 nums
> Nothing


-- Add (4, "four") to our original map.
moreNums = Map.insert 4 "four" nums

Map.member 4 moreNums
> True


-- Remove the entry for 1 from our original map.
fewerNums = Map.delete 1 nums

Map.toAscList fewerNums
> [(2,"two"),(3,"three")]


-- Create a new map and combine it with our original map.
-- fromList is right-biased: if a key is repeated the rightmost value is taken.
newNums = Map.fromList [(3,"new three"), (4,"new four"), (4,"newer four")]

-- union is left-biased: if a key occurs more than once the value from the
-- left map is taken.
Map.union newNums nums
> fromList [(1,"one"),(2,"two"),(3,"new three"),(4,"newer four")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `Data.Map` is the best for this kind of stuff, but I'd remark that it can also make sense to simply use a *list of tuples*, depending want you intend to do with this.

```
array = [ ('A', [1,2,3])
        , ('B', [4,5,6])
        , ('C', [7,8,9]) ]
```

This is something that's more sensibly called *array*, though IMO the terms “associative” and “array” are mutually contradicting. At any rate you can use the standard [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function on such lists, just be aware that it has *O* (*n*) complexity instead of the *O* (1) or *O* (log *n*) that purpose-designed structures achieve.